Why might allele frequencies change over many generations at neutral loci?
Lets say that a research team is looking at natural insect populations (e.g. beetle), and they find that allele frequencies at a locus in the genome have changed over the past few generations even though the locus is neutral. Why do the frequencies change at neutral loci?

There are four mechanisms by which allele frequencies can change over generations: mutation, genetic drift, gene flow, and natural selection. Which of these could affect a neutral locus?
